# How do you catch a click event with plain Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I know that when using jQuery you can do `$('element').click();` to catch the click event of an HTML element, but how do you do that with plain Javascript?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('element').onclick = function(e){
  alert('click');
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/e9jZW/1/

Comment: One thing to note: the jquery selector 'element' would be for an "element" tag, i.e. <element>...</element>. getElementById('element') selects the element with id "element", e.g. <div id="element">...</div>

Comment: @Asmor: True, in that case you could use `document.getElementsByTagName('div')` instead.  Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e9jZW/2/

Answer (score 16):

By adding an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) or setting the [`onclick` handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onclick) of an element:

```
var el = document.getElementById("myelement");

el.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert("Clicked");
});

// ... or ...

el.onclick = function() {
  alert("Clicked");
}
```

Note that the even listener style allows multiple listeners to be added whereas the callback handler style is exclusive (there can be only one).

If you need to add these handlers to multiple elements then you must acquire them as appropriate and add them to each one separately.

Comment: Is there any advantage to adding the event listener (over using onclick)?

Comment: In IE you have to use attachEvent rather than the standard addEventListener.

Comment: @chromedude: yes there are, notably that you can add multiple listeners and you can also explicitly prevent or allow event propagation to parent elements.  The linked MDN page about event listeners has more information.

Comment: @ashansky: true, IE doesn't support it until version 9, even though it is part of DOM level 2 (published in Nov 2000).

Comment: `There is a drawback to attachEvent, the value of "this" will be a reference to the window object instead of the element on which it was fired.` Goddammit IE...

Answer (score 5):

I usaly create a kind of global event handler, very powerful, you can capture className, of the event "types" nodeTypes, you name it, i hope people will find this useul

```
document.onclick = eventRef

function eventRef(evt) {
    var han;
    evt || (evt = window.event);

    if (evt) {
        var elem = evt.target ? han = evt.target : evt.srcElement && (han = evt.srcElement);

         // evt.type could be, mouseup, mousedown...
        // elem.id is the id or the element
        // elem.className is the class name of the element
        // you could nest expression, use substrings to extract part of a className
        if (evt.type=="click" && elem.id == "gotit" || elem.className == "someClassName") {  
            alert(elem.id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems less efficient than attaching the events to the individual element(s) you want.

Comment: well it would be for one or 3 elements, ill post a example to show how its more practical to use

Comment: Also, this function would be called for every click even if it doesn't have an event (even on links), seems inefficient.

Comment: @Rocket No rocket it wound not, and who would silly anuf to have two ID's the same :)

Comment: `han` seems redundant here, it's the same as `elem` and therefore isn't needed.

Comment: Huh?  What this have to do with having duplicate IDs?  I meant that every click would call this event and then it would have to check the ID (or class or w/e).  I think attaching individual events is more efficient.

Comment: @Rocket if you would like to continue ide be happy go in to a chat room and ill answer your comments

Comment: I was just wondering if this was more or less efficient, it seems like it would be less efficient.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4539/discussion-between-david-and-rocket)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend going with `addEventListener` instead of assigning the handler function directly.

```
var div = document.getElementById('test');
div.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
    console.log('CLICKED');
});
```

There are several reasons for that, but I am going to name those I find the most important:

1. You can't mistakenly add event listener to a non-DOM object with `addEventListener` - your code would fail instead of quietly assigning `onclick` function to some object
2. You can attach **only one** (without additional code manipulation for every handler that you want to add) event listener with `onclick` - something that might prove limiting

Comment: Well, you *could* attach multiple events with `onclick` if you backed up the original one first.  `var _click = el.onclick;  el.onclick=function(e){_click.call(this,e); //More code};`.

Comment: @Rocket 1st - thanks for the `attach` to `add` typo fix. :)
Secondly, of course I could do some "aspecting" around it, problem is - someone else who is using your code, writing it in parallel or customizing it may not be so generous...

Comment: Agreed.  Just sayin' you *could*, not that it was a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to vanilla js

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

// If the clicked element doesn't have the right selector, bail
if (!event.target.matches('input')) return;

// Don't follow the link
event.preventDefault();

// Log the clicked element in the console
console.log(event.target);

}, false);
```

This also show which element is c

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting article about that, i used the same approach some times, basically, you add the event handler to `window`.
http://mislav.uniqpath.com/js/handling-events-on-elements/

Comment: Isn't attaching the event and then figuring out what to call less efficient than just attaching the event to multiple elements?